# Laravel Livewire @script

Tags: laravel, components

I have this button in the blade file of a `livewire` component:

`<button type="button" title="Adauga o disciplina noua" class="ml-2 my-auto bg-blue-500 text-white px-2 py-1 rounded-lg" onclick="adaugaSelect()">+</button>`

and the function:

```
`
@script
<script>
    function adaugaSelect() {
        
    }
</script>
@endscript`
```

And in console I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: adaugaSelect is not defined . From what i read there might be an issue with the @script directive`.

Is there any fixes?

googling and moving the function outside the blade file, but is not doable

Comment: What do you want actually to achieve? Do you have this script before component ending tag `</div>` ? Do you have those scripts pushed to master layout?

Comment: the adaugaSelect() function on the plus button just adds another select field on form. The script is outside the div, in the specific component, not pushed in master layout

Answer (score 0):

I also have noticed this issue in [livewire3](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/javascript#using-javascript-in-livewire-components) .. I solve it by not using @script at all.. at will work without that just fine... here is an example

```
<div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</div>
 
@script
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert('Hello World!');
    }
</script>
@endscript
```

thats showing error just like yours...

so i just remove the @script tag

```
<div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert('Hello World!');
    }
</script>
```

back in livewire V2 you will find that they where using @push("scripts") but it was also not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

apparently the @script ... @endscript issue was solved on Livewire version 3.3

try to update the Livewire package

`composer update livewire/livewire`